# Follow the ASP.NET ActionResult after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

A controller returns an `ActionResult`, i.e.:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    // do something

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Orders", null });
}
```

this works fine is I use an `ActionLink` in the view.
But the actual call is done via Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Orders/Delete",
    cache: false,
    data: { id: $("#btnCancel").data("id") }
}).done(function (response) {
    $("html").html(response);
});
```

with the:

```
$("html").html(response);
```

line I'm trying to follow the returned html page.
It doesn't work: the html is rendered wrong (layout and colors are different) and even the address is not correct (of course it remains on the current page, instead to follow the Controller path).

I'm not sure if this is possible to do in jQuery.
Why I use an Ajax call instead of the ActionLink? Because I need to wait a confirm by the user:

```
$("#btnCancel").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title: "@Resources.MsgCancelOrderTitle",
        text: "@Resources.MsgCancelOrderText",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
        confirmButtonText: "@Resources.MsgCancelOrderConfirm",
        cancelButtonText: "@Resources.MsgCancelOrderCancel",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: true
    },
        function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                swal({
                    title: "@Resources.MsgCancelOrderSuccessTitle",
                    text: "@Resources.MsgCancelOrderSuccessText",
                    type: "success"
                },
                    function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Orders/Delete",
                            cache: false,
                            data: { id: $("#btnCancel").data("id") }
                        }).done(function (response) {
                            $("html").html(response);
                        });
                    });
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Can you see the calls to the server using developer tools or fiddler?

Comment: "the address is not correct (of course it remains on the current page, instead to follow the Controller path)." Yes, that's the whole point of ajax - to avoid page refreshes, postbacks or redirects. If you want to redirect to another view, then don't bother with ajax, it defeats the entire purpose of it. Generally an ajax call returns either some data (JSON or XML) or a small snippet of HTML which is designed to fit somewhere within the page which made the ajax call (generally implemented in MVC as a Partial View)

Comment: @ADyson In this case I need to redirect because I will update the model. But I also need to show the alert: is there a way to achieve both things?

Comment: Yes, you can just use some other kind of button which causes the alert to be shown, and then if the user confirms, programatically cause a postback.

Comment: @ADyson I don't know how to do that. Would you mind to put me on the right way?

Comment: "programatically cause a postback", is what I tried to do (wrongly) with the Ajax call. I'm googling for the correct way to do that.

Comment: Well you've already done the first part (show the alert via a button). Once the user confirms, then if the request needed uses the GET method (like your example) then simply a call to `window.location.href` with the appropriate URL will do it. If it was using POST, then normally there'd be a HTML form you could instruct to submit itself.

Comment: P.S. To go back to your earlier point "In this case I need to redirect because I will update the model. ". With a different design you wouldn't necessarily have to do that - like I said, ajax calls can return data, which you can use to help alter the contents of the HTML within the page you're already on (e.g. to remove an item, or display new items). But that requires a bigger re-think of your application structure.

Comment: @ADyson got it. I'm using elsewhere Ajax calls in the "right" manner. Anyway if you want to post your last comments as an answer I think it's acceptable!

Comment: @Mark, the way I do that is putting my submit button inside the confirmation dialog. The dialog initially remains hidden ("display:none;"). All I have is a click handler and an ordinary submit button in confirmation dialog. For this to work, submit and confirmation are inside html form. No redirect, no ajax.

Comment: @Mark I have added an answer - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect to another view, then don't bother with ajax, it defeats the entire purpose of it. Generally an ajax call returns either some data (JSON or XML) or a small snippet of HTML which is designed to fit somewhere within the page which made the ajax call (generally implemented in MVC as a Partial View).

If you need the redirect, then do it like this:

Once the user confirms their choice via the alert box, then if the request needed uses the GET method (like your example) then simply a call to `window.location.href` with the appropriate URL will do it. If it was using POST, then normally there'd be a HTML form you could instruct to submit itself.